# Kernel 4.19.2 nividia-415 can't boot

Tags: nvidia, kernel

I installed Kernel 4.19.2 on my 18.04.1 machine. (threadripper 2, 1080 nvidia card)
At first I got errors, so I updated Nvidia drivers, reinstalled the kernel and got no errors.

However, now, when I boot, the text is big like no video drivers are used.

Once it gets to where I should get an X login screen, the screen seems to just keep flickering, like it can't find a resolution that works?

If I boot to recovery mode and apt remove nvidia*, I can then boot in fine and everything looks right. But then I'm not on the proprietary drivers.

Any idea where I would look for log errors? I looked through syslog, kernel log and x.0 log... But nothing seemed to stick out.

Anyone else have this issue?

Thanks!

EDIT: I should mention that nvidia-415 worked fine with kernel 4.18.x...